# How to print in a single line without using end =''

Tags: python

I have a task to create a row of numbers. what I have now works and prints on one line. I want to try to use it without end. What I've tried already is creating a variable `new_line = ""` and adding that / equaling that to the string in the print line. I also need to be able to print another "|" at the end of the string only and I can't do that with end.

```
def print_row(n, max_power, column_width):
    count = 0
    exponent = max_power
    max_power = 0
    while count < exponent:
        max_power = max_power + 1
        value = power(n, max_power)
        print("|",padded(value, column_width),end='')
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use `end=''`? If it's a solution to your problem, then why would you not want to use it?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman in the question the OP claims: "I also need to be able to print another "|" at the end of the string only and i can't do that with end."

Comment: @Ted Klein Bergman in another line of my code I'm able to use my new line method. when I tried to the same for this part it doesn't work so I'm trying to know why. also for the print at the end wont work with end

Comment: Then this is a bit confusing and should probably be reformulated: _"what I have now works and prints on one line"._ Also, printing an additional `|` at the end of the line is still plausible using your current solution. Just print it after the `while` loop.

Comment: @Alz you can print a "|" at the end only by putting: `print("|", end='')` after the `while` loop. Also, you could build a string in the loop and print it after with a single print statement, like: `while count < exponent:` `string += "|" + padded(value, column_width)`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman agreed

Answer (score 1):

You're using the loop to control the wrong thing. Use the loop to build a list of values to be *combined* using `|` as a separator, then print that string with one call to `print`.

```
def print_row(n, max_power, column_width):
    values = [padded(power(n, p), column_width) for p in range(max_power)]
    print("|" + "|".join(values), end="|")
```

The initial `"|"` can be added to the value to actually print (as shown), or could be output with a preceding call to `print("|", end='')`.

Comment: I believe it starts with a "|" also.

Comment: Yeah, I'm slowly getting to that :)

Comment: Haha, no worries.

Comment: My understanding of what the OP wants is evolving along with the answer...